# How can a Gloomblade fighter extend the list of throwable two-handed weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, weapons, fighter, throwing-things

I'm currently building a [Gloomblade](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Fighter%20Gloomblade) fighter with the [Two-Handed Fighter](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Fighter%20Two-Handed%20Fighter) archetype. The ranged option of this character is thrown shadow weapons, and I am looking for ways to expand the list of options.

I use the Gloomblade and Two-Handed Fighter and apply the bonus of weapon training to shadow two-handed weapons only (it was pointed out below that they do not stack, but please assume they do with GM authorization). I also plan to use [Gloomstorm](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gloomstorm) and [Two-Handed Thrower](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Two-Handed%20Thrower) (assuming the GM will allow Gloomstorm to count as Quick Draw for the purpose of this feat). This allows me to throw at a full rate of attacks.

Now, the problem I have is that I am restricted to shadow, melee, two-handed weapons with a range increment. There are exactly two of them, the martial [Syringe Spear](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Syringe%20spear) and the simple [Spear](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spear) (as well as five exotic options).

Is there a way to expand this list further? I can forfeit the Weapon Training bonus to throw one-handed weapons having a range increment (adding four additional options), or throw two-handed melee weapons (e.g. a greataxe) at a -4 penalty, but I'm looking for ways to keep both bonuses.

The other techniques that I know are not available because the [Throw Anything](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Throw%20Anything) feat works with improvised (not manufactured) weapons and the [Throwing](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Throwing) property is not a valid choice for shadow weapons.

Comment: Gloomblade two-handed fighter is not legit to begin with.  Both archetypes replace Armor Training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Take levels in the brawler class

The martial [flexibility ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Brawler/#TOC-Martial-Flexibility-Ex-) allows you to become proficient in additional types of weapons for a limited duration, which expands your choice to allow you to summon exotic weapons without spending feats on them.

### Martial Master fighter archetype

Similar to the brawler, the [Martial Master](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/martial-master/) fighter archetype may become proficient with a type of weapon of their choice. This archetype replaces both weapon training and armor training though.

### Ioun stones

The [Opalescent White Pyramid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/opalescent-white-pyramid-ioun-stone/) ioun stone grants your character proficiency with one type of weapon. The cracked version makes you treat that weapon as being *familiar* to your character (treat as martial) and costs 1,500 gp.

### Be a quick learner tiefling

It is a fairly common combination to be a [Quick Learner](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/equipment-traits/quick-learner/) [Tiefling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling/) with the [Arms Master](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/arms-master-tiefling-faultspawn/) racial trait, which can reduce the penalty for using a weapon which you are not proficient with to -2 at the first attack and no penalty from then on.

Answer (score 0):

### There are a few ways to expand your list of weapons you summon with Gloomblade.

- **[Exotic Weapon Proficiency](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/exotic-weapon-proficiency-combat/):** This allows you to expand your list to include weapons that require exotic weapon proficiency. It is slow though, as it only does 1 weapon at a time.
- **[Improvisational Focus](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Improvisational%20Focus):** This makes you proficient with improvised weapons, allowing your gloomblade to summon giant plates to throw with [Throw Anything](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Throw%20Anything).
- **Plead with the GM:** If the GM houserules the two archetypes to stack together, see if he'll let gloomblade summon throwing weapons as well, instead of only just melee ones.

<sub><sup>This answer has been edited to be more focused on the question asked, see the edit history for the original answer.</sup></sub>

Comment: Upon rereading the question, you're exactly right. `:-)` Consider leading with that? (Also, Improvisational Focus may not work as it doesn't actually grant proficiency with all improvised weapons but says, "You are considered proficient with *the* improvised weapon." Which one? The one in your hand with which you're making an attack. *Sigh.* Darn you, *Pathfinder.*)

Comment: _"Vaguely worded ability/feat"_ - Paizo, on everything.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the question to reflect that the archetypes are not supposed to stack and refocus on the main part of the question about throwing two-handed weapons (which you address in the second part of your answer and was pointed out by @HeyICanChan).